Does a buffer need to be marked as volatile?
I've seen many examples explaining usage of volatile keyword but all of those refer to a single variables e.g tick counter incremented in ISR and then read in main loop. But what about a buffer that is shared between main loop and ISR, where main loop is producer and ISR consumer (or another way around).
Let's say that I have a simple ring buffer struct:
struct RingBuffer
{
 uint8_t *data;
 uint32_t write_index;
 uint32_t read_index;
};

struct RingBuffer buffer;

Does data have to be volatile ? Or whole buffer (which also implies that function parameter also have to be volatile) ? I took a look at few implementations of a such data structure and I couldn't seen any volatile there and that bothers me a lot.
I wrote simple program on stm32 for driving lcd display with buffering. Code looks like this:
struct OutputLine
{
    GPIO_TypeDef *gpio;
    uint16_t pin;
};

typedef struct OutputLine OutputLine_t;

struct HD44780
{
    OutputLine_t enable;
    OutputLine_t rs;
    OutputLine_t rw;
    OutputLine_t data[4]; // data[0..3] == D4..7
    Fifo_t fifo;
};

In main loop I checked if lcd was busy and if not then if there's something in queue. Commands to lcd was sent in timer irq
while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      HD44780_Update(&lcd);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }

void HD44780_Update(HD44780_t *lcd)
{
    if (Fifo_Empty(&lcd->fifo)) {
        return;
    }
    if (HD44780_Busy(lcd)) {
        return;
    }
    HD44780_FifoItem_t item;
    Fifo_Read(&lcd->fifo, &item);
    HD44780_WriteByte(lcd, item.byte, item.rs);
}

void TIM6_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (LL_TIM_IsActiveFlag_UPDATE(TIM6)) {
        LL_TIM_ClearFlag_UPDATE(TIM6);
        i = (i + 1) & 1;
        HD44780_ClearDisplay(&lcd);
        HD44780_Puts(&lcd, strings[i], strlen(strings[i]));
    }
}

Result was correct wether Fifo_t was volatile or not.

volatile (for ring buffers) is useful in embedded when the ISR will add to the ring buffer. But, the base task level would have to wrap access in disable_interrupts, process buffer, enable_interrupts. In which case, volatile isn't needed. For multithreaded, use of either mutexes and/or stdatomic.h primitives is warranted. So, again, volatile not needed. volatile is most useful for accessing memory mapped hardware registers/devices, usually via an inline function or macro: uint32_t getreg(uint32_t regaddr) { return *(volatile uint32_t *) (uintptr_t) regaddr; }

In bare-metal systems volatile is oftentimes used as, pardon simplification, "poor man's atomic". Sometimes this happens due to lack of atomic operations on some architectures e.g. on AVR.
Note also that GPIO_TypeDef does contain volatiles inside, see here. __IO is a shorthand for volatile, which here represents memory-mapped ports.

@CraigEstey but how disabling and re-enabling interrupts affects meaning of volatile ? In my understaning it only provides atomic read to data that can be changed somwhere else than in main loop (so volatile still needed)

@CraigEstey basically what you wrote is very imprecise and misleading.

volatile means effectively "modifying this variable causes a side effect, read and store it from/into its memory address". This enforced side effect prevents the variable from being optimized away e.g. by storing it inside a CPU register, therefore making it behave the desired way when accessed not from the standard predictable sequential way. However, as far as I know atomics (e.g. std::atomic from C++ or atomic_int from C) should also be prevented from this kind of optimization (provided the strict memory model is used).

@abramek Possibly. But, cli/sti is usually marked with something that indicates that there is a memory barrier (e.g. asm volatile("nop") ::: "memory");). It doesn't affect the meaning of volatile only the usage (whether it is needed or not). And, it doesn't provide atomic read (ala atomic_load). On a single core system, if you do cli, you guaranteed that whatever you do until the sti won't be interfered with (this could be thousands of instructions, if you wish). Thus, an ISR and a main will have "an atomic view" of the data ...

@gulpr In what way? Your comment is the equivalent of an OP saying "my program doesn't work"

Neither disabling/enabling interrupts imply volatile access of whatever is between them; nor does volatile imply atomicity of any kind.

@alagner volatile does absolutely nothing in regards of atomicity. A variable shared with an ISR does not become safe with regards to race condition bugs just because it was declared volatile. Similarly, just because a MCU is an 8-bitter, C code operations on 8 bit variables are not guaranteed to be atomic either, because the C code does not necessarily translate to a single, uninterruptable assembler instruction.

@CraigEstey Drivers shouldn't be meddling with the global interrupt mask ever. That can cause all manner of very hard to track down bugs for other parts of the program. Instead, drivers should toggle the specific interrupt flag. So if you want to protect against race condition bugs in the ADC driver for accessing a variable shared with the ADC ISR, then the driver should toggle the ADC interrupt mask, not the global one! Additionally, just doing cli/sti is harmful in another way too, since you don't stack it, you destroy whatever value the i flag had previously.

@Lundin I guess limited size of comments has led most of us here towards oversimplifications.
As for global cli/sti toggle: I agree... and then comes the vendor-provided stdlib, e.g. ATOMIC_BLOCK from AVR.

@alagner Most of these libs were written by various hobbyists and PC programmers. That's one of the dangers of open source - no quality concerns exist. Not that Atmel themselves managed to ever provide anything better lib-wise... silicon manufacturers have an even worse rep than hobbyists in terms of source code quality.

@Lundin in case of AVR this comes from their datasheets. The better part of it is, that they at least recommend saving and restoring the global interrupt state, not blindly changing it. Or maybe I'm just trying to see the silver lining here. BTW, it's not only Atmel, deadlocking libraries from ST were also one hot topic some years ago ;)

@alagner I've yet to see code from any silicon vendor which couldn't have been written any worse by fresh out of school engineers. I suspect they let some "FAE" code this stuff in their free time or something...

What is volatile? It probably the most misunderstood keyword in the C language (maybe except restrict).

volatile informs the compiler that the object (variable) is side effects prone. It means that it can be changed by something which is not visible for the compiler in a normal program execution path. For example by the hardware (DMA, hardware register) or signal (exception) handler which is not called by the program.

Example:
uint32_t counter;

void TIM6_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* .... */
    counter++;
}

void foo(void)
{
    while(counter < 1000);
    printf("x");
}

and the resulting code: https://godbolt.org/z/h3qz7Y5W6
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L8
        ldr     r3, [r3]
.L6:
        cmp     r3, #1000
        bcc     .L6

As you can see without volatile the counter is loaded into register only once and function foo will end in the dead loop even if counter reaches 1000. With volatile counter is read from memory before every use as compiler knows that it is side effects prone: https://godbolt.org/z/KThnG3sq4
The resulting code:
foo:
        ldr     r2, .L8
.L6:
        ldr     r3, [r2]
        cmp     r3, #1000
        bcc     .L6

Now the counter is loaded into the register at every use.
volatile does not guarantee atomicity cache coherency.
As volatile objects have to be read from their permanent storage every time they are used it is not good to have volatile big data structures. So answering your question - no do not make the whole structure volatile, only members which are side effects prone.

volatile means both that the object may be modified by things outside the direct control of the program and that the program itself reading or writing the object is a side effect.

@KeithThompson any access to volatile object is side-effect in the Standard understanding.
